# Hazelcast : How to get notified when item expires on map

Tags: hazelcast

In hazelcast is it possible to get Async. notified when item expired on the Cache Map. In EhCache they have this feature via [1]

[1] http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/cache-event-listeners

-Malinga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking about [EntryListener::entryEvicted](http://www.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/EntryListener.html#entryEvicted%28com.hazelcast.core.EntryEvent%29)?

Comment: Exactly what im looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Eviction can also occure due to map size restrictions and not only for TTL expired!

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Hazelcast 3.6, expiry events are differentiated from eviction events. Expiry is the event only fired in case of expiration due to ttl (time-to-live seconds) where entries can be evicted because of size constraints (eviction event).

Check the documentation for [EntryExpiredListener](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/javadoc/com/hazelcast/map/listener/EntryExpiredListener.html)

More infor here: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/6311